# How to limit the initial number of records fetched on Compass?

Tags: mongodb-compass

When I navigate to a particular collection, Compass tries to fetch 20 records from the server. How do I limit this to just one?

I am using version 1.15.4-win32-x64.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the limit option in the Filter

[image]

Comment: That would work for subsequent queries. But as soon as you click on a collection, the query screen pulls in 20 records. How do I change that behavior?